# Storing User-Pass logins in json file?

Tags: php, json, authentication

I've been tasked with creating a system to this, the issue is I can’t store anything in a database as the server is set up ridiculously badly and basically any database related storage is unavailable for use.

So I came to the conclusion of storing any and all data in a `json` format. Now my issue is I need to store user credentials as access is only allowed to authorised users.

How would I go about storing these user credentials? Would I store them with [**`one-way password hashes`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/401684/2518525) or should I use something like `mcrypt_encrypt()` & `mcrypt_decrypt()` respectively?

**Encryption Function**

```
function encrypt($string) {
        if (extension_loaded('mcrypt')) {
            return trim($this->base64_url_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->key, $string, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Decryption Function**

```
function decrypt($string) {
        if (extension_loaded('mcrypt')) {
            return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->key, $this->base64_url_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

And the following two `base64` functions from [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177757/custom-implementation-of-base32-or-base64/10177988#10177988):

```
function base64_url_encode($input) {
        return strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/=', '-_,');
    }

    function base64_url_decode($input) {
        return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_,', '+/='));
    }
```

Comment: I'd personally avoid having mutliple calls inside other calls, it makes it slightly harder to debug & read on the later, add some new lines with comments, it'll assist when looking back at the code

Comment: are you sure you can use SQLite  ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what storage mechanism you use (database, text file, etc.), you should never ever store plain-text or encrypted passwords. Always salt and hash them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401656/secure-hash-and-salt-for-php-passwords?lq=1

Comment: @Dagon absolutely no way, the people before me set up the ugliest thing I've ever laid my hands on

Comment: @jeroen as stated I asked which way it should be done?

Comment: you know it just uses a flat file, no db engine needs be installed

Comment: @Dagon unfortunately I can't even use that :(

Comment: As Darren says, always salt and hash them. Use[password_hash](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) if you can, or the [compatibility library otherwise](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use one way encryption when dealing with user passwords. The potential damages of an someone gaining access to your server and recovering passwords are just too great. I'd recommend a memory-intensive, multiple-round hashing algorithm such as bcrypt/scrypt.

If you must use JSON, store your passwords hashed, and then when a user logs in, rehash their password and compare.

```
{
 "users": [{
   "name": "john",
   "password": "sjh77DGGD..."
 }, {
   ...
 }]
}
```

Comment: Would it be better to store all possible logins in one file or have a file for each seperate user?

Comment: In your case it might actually make more sense to store them as separate files. If you're going to be reading a file every time someone logs in you might as well read a smaller file. This would be a lot easier if you were using SQLite. If you can store a json file can't you just store a .sqlite db file?

Comment: Basically any `sql*` file, related anything is automatically removed. I have no access to the server at all so I have no choice but this really.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Sometimes we've all gotta work under crazy constraints :D

Comment: Do you have to store any additional information about your users aside from just the passwords?

Comment: luckily just username and passwords to prevent random people accessing!